# Getting table data to Bootstrap Modal using Sinatra ERB templating

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, sinatra

I have a simple table which, using ERB templating (i.e. `<%= =>`), displays a table of data.

Each row in the table has an edit button to edit the contents of the row. I am trying to make it such that when I click on the edit button, a Bootstrap Modal will pop up with the contents of the row in `<textarea>` tags but whenever I do this, it only always displays the contents of the first row.

Here is the table in the ERB file

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-list">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th><em class="fa fa-cog"></em></th>
                    <th>Question</th>
                    <th>Answer</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <% $snippety.each do |snippet| %>
                      <tr>
                        <td align="center">
                          <a class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#basicModal4" aria-hidden="true" name="btn"  data-modal-type="confirm"><em class="fa fa-pencil"></em></a>
                          <a class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#basicModal3" aria-hidden="true" name="btn"  data-modal-type="confirm"><em class="fa fa-trash"></em></a>
                        </td>
                        <td><%=snippet["question"]%></td>
                        <td><%=snippet["answer"]%></td>
                        <td>
                          <form onsubmit="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete the Snippet?')" action='/api/v1/snippets/delete/<%= snippet["id"] %>' method="post">
                            <input type="submit" value="Delete" class="delete"> | <a id="button" shape="circle" color="black" href='/api/v1/snippets/edit/<%= snippet["id"] %>'>Edit</a>
                          </form>
                        </td>
                      </tr>

                      <!-- DELETE MODAL -->
                      <div class="modal fade" id="basicModal3">
                        <div class="modal-dialog" role="dialog">
                          <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                              </button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body">
                              <p style="text-align:center">WARNING</p>
                              <p style="text-align:center">This will delete the Snippet forever and cannot be recovered</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                              <form action="/api/v1/snippets/delete/<%= snippet["id"] %>" method="POST">

                              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Delete</button>
                            </form>

                              <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>

                      <!-- EDIT MODAL -->
                      <div class="modal fade" id="basicModal4" role="dialog">
                        <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
                          <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                              <h4 class="modal-title">Edit Snippet</h4>
                            </div>
                            <form action="/api/v1/snippets/edited/" method="POST">
                                <div class="modal-body">
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                      <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="comment">Question</label>
                                        <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="comment" name="question"><%=snippet["question"]%></textarea>
                                      </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                      <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="comment">Answer</label>
                                        <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="comment" name="answer"><%=snippet["answer"]%></textarea>
                                      </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                    <button type="reset" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save Snippet</button>
                                </div>
                              </form>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <%end%>
                    </tbody>
            </table>
```

I know I can open a new page with the table data to be edited via a Sinatra controller but I don't want to have to do that.

Comment: You are creating `n` number of modals (where n is equal to the number of `snippets` but they all have the same DOM id so apparently it is opening the first modal with that id that it finds in the DOM. I think it would be easier to create this modal 1 time outside the loop and just javascript to set the form action on the button click instead

Comment: That was my thought process too. Any tips on how to do that?